# Change Icon User Login Screen, and Background, CentOS 7

Tags: centos, kde, login, icons, user-interface

I have CentOS 7 and I want the Icon User on the Login Screen...

I was trying in the `System Settings` -> `Account Details`, Click over Image

But this method doesn't work...

The Second Part, is changing the Background Image...

Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Edit

**Edit**

```
# gsettings list-keys org.gnome.login-screen
fallback-logo
disable-user-list
allowed-failures
enable-smartcard-authentication
banner-message-enable
enable-password-authentication
disable-restart-buttons
logo
enable-fingerprint-authentication
banner-message-text
# gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.login-screen
org.gnome.login-screen fallback-logo ''
org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list false
org.gnome.login-screen allowed-failures 3
org.gnome.login-screen enable-smartcard-authentication false
org.gnome.login-screen banner-message-enable false
org.gnome.login-screen enable-password-authentication true
org.gnome.login-screen disable-restart-buttons false
org.gnome.login-screen logo '/usr/share/pixmaps/fedora-gdm-logo.png'
org.gnome.login-screen enable-fingerprint-authentication true
org.gnome.login-screen banner-message-text ''
# gsettings get org.gnome.login-screen logo
'/usr/share/pixmaps/fedora-gdm-logo.png'
```

Now set my new image logo!

```
# gsettings set org.gnome.login-screen logo '/usr/share/pixmaps/faces/penguin.jpg'

(process:5208): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed
#
```

Comment: check this link https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/desktop_migration_and_administration_guide/customizing-login-screen and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/desktop_migration_and_administration_guide/configuration-overview-gsettings-dconf

Comment: Check this method https://www.netsarang.com/forum/xmanager/4076/how_to_configure_xmanager_to_centos7